# Fixed-Point In Matlab: can it be implemented without Designer/Library?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, fixed

I worked in matlab on my design and I used floating point.  To rewrite the design in FPGA I  need to work with fixed point.

In Matlab licence I have there is not Fixed Point Designeer or library to use function as `fi`, `numerictype`, ...

Is it possible to work/implement the fixed-point without this function? FOr example, can all these function be written?